# Full screen website in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, fullscreen

I have a Flash website that I would like to set at 100% height and 100% width, but at the moment I get a black border. However if I make the website fullscreen and then exit fullscreen mode the border disappears... Any ideas of how to properly make it fill the web page?

At the moment I have the SWF in a div as follows:

```
#flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
```

You can see the site here http://edharrisondesign.com/remembrance-site/

Comment: That is a cool site, one 'bug' I found is when you have the step where you hover over the soldiers to make em change to a cross or a wounded soldier, if you move very fast over the soldiers some of them just disappear but they aren't changed to crossers/wounded soldiers.. This just happens if you move to quickly over the soldiers :). Just to let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things I am noticing:

1. The content area of the SWF remains locked in its aspect ratio at all times. This is good, as it keeps the content from looking stretched. It does, however, lead to letterboxing (black borders on either top/bottom or left/right). If this is what you are referring to, I would leave it the way it is, personally. Better to letterbox than to stretch images. But that is just me.
2. The SWF goes fullscreen just fine, it's the content that does not change size. It remains exactly the same size as it was prior to going fullscreen. My guess, is you don't set the height and width of your container to be `stage.stageHeight` and `stage.stageWidth` (You would obviously need to take aspect ratio into account) when you go fullscreen.